# Add four columns from Datatable to list view

Tags: vb.net

I have list of columns in DataTable to be added in list view. I have specified to the listview of columns in the order to appear and Datas as well.

```
    EmailAddress  Subject     RecievedDate
     cd@cd.in      Hello      02/06/2011 23:00
```

This the format to appear.Please anyone can help on this

EDIT:

Code so far:

```
For i = 0 To objDataTable.Rows.Count drow = objDataTable.Rows(i) 
    Dim lvwItem As ListViewItem = New lvwItem(drow("SenderEmail"))    
    'lvwItem.SubItems.Add(drow("SenderEmail")) 
    lvwItem.SubItems.Add(drow("EmailSubject")) 
    lvwItem.SubItems.Add(drow("RecievedDate").ToString()) 
    lvwItem.SubItems.Add(drow("AssignedTo").ToString()) 
    LOV.Items.Add(lvwItem) 
Next
```

Comment: Could you add some code to show what you've tried?

Comment: For i = 0 To objDataTable.Rows.Count
            drow = objDataTable.Rows(i)
            Dim lvwItem As ListViewItem = New lvwItem(drow("SenderEmail"))
            'lvwItem.SubItems.Add(drow("SenderEmail"))
            lvwItem.SubItems.Add(drow("EmailSubject"))
            lvwItem.SubItems.Add(drow("RecievedDate").ToString())
            lvwItem.SubItems.Add(drow("AssignedTo").ToString())
            LOV.Items.Add(lvwItem)
        Next

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample looks *almost* correct. One error is this line:

```
Dim lvwItem As ListViewItem = New lvwItem(drow("SenderEmail"))
```

This should be:

```
Dim lvwItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(drow("SenderEmail").ToString())
```

Apart from that you need to make sure your listview is in details view and you actually have the columns you require (otherwise nothing will be shown when in details view):

```
    With listview1
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Add("Email Address")
        .Columns.Add("Subject")
        .Columns.Add("Recived Date")
        'etc
    End With
```

One other small issue is This line:

```
For i = 0 To objDataTable.Rows.Count
```

Should be

```
For i = 0 To objDataTable.Rows.Count - 1
```

Comment: When try this i get error in this line Dim lvwItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(drow("SenderEmail"))

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it seems the problem might be that the line should look like this: Dim lvwItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(drow("SenderEmail").ToString())